# Code Optimization for Min Swaps for making first 2D array identical to other

Tags: python-3.x

I have written this code for finding the minimum number of swaps for two 2D arrays to make the first one identical to other. Can someone optimize it more?

```
for each in range(int(input())):
    m = int(input().split(' ')[0])
    a1 = []
    a2 = []
    for i in range(m):
        a1 += [int(k) for j in input() for k in j]
    for i in range(m):
        a2 += [int(k) for j in input() for k in j]
    if a1.count(1) == a2.count(1):
        c = 0
        for j in range(len(a1)):
            if a1[j] != a2[j]: 
                c += 1
        print(c//2)
    else:
        print(-1)
```

Comment: Does this code work? If so, this question should be posted to [codereview.se].

Comment: @ForceBru yes posted it there on code review, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

This question has moved to Code Review.

Details are visible at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226789/minimum-number-of-swaps-for-two-2d-arrays-to-make-the-first-one-identical-to-other